# Inconsistent thumbnail generation in Finder?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, exact-duplicates, new-users

Ok, just saying, but this site seems a bit broken.  The exact question I want to ask has *been* addressed, but I can't enter that conversation/thread because I don't have 50 reputation points.  So ... I am allowed to create a duplicate and redundant question, but not provide useful information to an existing thread???

Relative to the earlier thread ... I've tried every solution proposed there and none of them have worked.  Maybe since the last response in that thread someone has come across another approach?  Note that SOME of my icons (all .jpg) have thumbnails.

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain what your issue is, and how those answers didn’t help you. You will be able to comment on all posts in this thread. See [tour] too see how this site works. [help] for further doubts. :)

Comment: Can you please add a link to the question you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for raising a point here. Are you saying the decision to limit comments to accounts with reputation is broken or that the rep limit chosen is wrong?

The best way to enter the conversation is to make an edit to any answer that’s close and needs an edit or to make a new answer that totally nails the point you wish to make.

There’s no need to have this be a forum with lots of discussion and chat per the design of the site.

Does this help you decide what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have the same problem as described in an existing question but none of the answers worked for you, there is always the option to use the „Ask Question“ button to ask a new question. Make sure to describe the problem you want to solve, add a reference/link to the original question and also describe the things you‘ve tried and how they failed.